# java web services - request, acknowledgment and response

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have to develop a Java web service that get a request and sends immediately an acknowledgment (synchronous), so that far, it is simple.

Next, the web service has to do multiple checks on the request, then send a response according to that (synchronous too, because i don't have a callback endpoint from the client).

The problem is that i can send the ackowledgment, and i launch the multiple checks in another thread, but when the checks are done, the client already recieved his response, and i can't send another one.

Here's what i did for now:

```
@WebService
public class Configuration {

    @Resource WebServiceContext context;

    @WebMethod
    public ReqAckType configure(@XmlElement(required = true) @WebParam(name = "reqType")
                                       ReqType req) {

        ReqAckType ack = new ReqAckType();
        ack.setReceptionTime(Calendar.getInstance());

        ChecksScheduler cs = ChecksScheduler.getInstance();

        Checks checks = cs.schedule(req);

        ack.setInternalId(checks.getId());

        return ack;
    }

}
```

If anyone can help me figure out how to send two separate message (ack and response), knowing that i have to send them separately and the checks take too much time (it's because of that, that i have to send and ack), i would be thankful.

I am using Oracle Fusion Middleware (Weblogic, JDeveloper, ..)

Comment: What does the ack actually DO that the client doesn't know from the fact that it didn't get any error when sending the request? If it does simple checks, you could split the whole thing in two methods.

Comment: The ack simply returns when the request arrives (so yeah, nothing apart from the fact that the request has arrived to the correct endpoint -plus the reception time info).
I can't split in two methods because the client will only call this method and once.

Comment: In this case I would personally forgo the ack, since if there was a network problem or similar, the network layer should produce an error anyway...

Comment: Yeah, but this must be done this way, is there no other way?
I'll try and convince the other part's team that this is the right way to do it.

Comment: A (SOAP) WebService means, to my best knowledge, request -> response. Perhaps it would be possible to create something by keeping the HTTP connection open, but I doubt that this is somehow still technically a normal WebService.

Comment: Add a reply so i can accept it if you want to.

Comment: Nice thought, but not required, thanks.